# Is there an opencv or python api call that calculates the jaccard similarity of two bounding boxes?

Tags: python, opencv

Is there an opencv or python api call that calculates the jaccard similarity of two bounding boxes?

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is ,I used to work with SimpleCV library for doing tasks that were look like yours

see this page
http://simplecv-examples.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Comment: i searched for Jaccard and nothing came up :/

Comment: I suggest use classes in this library for make your own,I'm not sure you can find jaccard directly!

Comment: its not immediately apparent where i should look for it. i looked in a couple of places in that link :(

Comment: i think i found the src https://github.com/sightmachine/SimpleCV/tree/master/SimpleCV/examples/detection
but i couldnt find any reference to comparison of boxes or rectangles or to jaccard...